# Error while migrating from vaadin 7 to vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin7, vaadin8

I am migrating my application from vaadin 7 to vaadin 8 and following exactly same steps mentioned in the link
But I am getting error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler
```

when I run following command to compile the widgetset

> > mvn  -X vaadin:compile -Dvaadin.charts.developer.license= package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

I took out all the addons and kept only the chart one. Can you please help me what might be causing the error. I could upload the POM file, but its big.

Edit:
I noticed that classpath is not set up when I am running mvn vaadin:compile

Comment: **1)** How did you figure out the cp is not set? **2)** I guess you'll have to post the pom so we can reproduce the issue ourselves, because I can't think of any easy way to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I was able to compile the widgetset file. I dont have specific reason why/how. I tried couple of times with different set of combination and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured I had some issues, like incompatible version of add-ons ,etc. When I used the compatible ones, it got fixed.